# Using dynamic type

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I'm using a System.Window.Controls Webbrowser (WPF) which is throwing up a few anomolies here and there.

Normally if I want to get access to the webbrowser document in Winforms and click an element I would use

```
       HtmlDocument document = webNav.webBrowser1.Document;
       document.GetElementById("id_of_element").InvokeMember("Click");
```

However, in WPF it throws error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`.

I can get around this by using

```
       dynamic document = webNav.webBrowser1.Document;
       document.GetElementById("id_of_element").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Is there a better/preferred method or is this an acceptable use of the dynamic type?  (are there any examples of acceptable use of dynamic type?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, you are missing an explicit cast:

```
 HtmlDocument document = (HtmlDocument)webNav.webBrowser1.Document;
```

*Assuming you have `using System.Windows.Forms;` at the top of the file (to make the code above shorter).*

I knew this because of the line,

> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

No use of `dynamic` is needed in this instance.

Comment: It solves the initial error for me. But later when I use `string htmlText = document.documentElement.InnerHtml.ToString();` it now throws error `'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'documentElement' and no extension method 'documentElement' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: That's because that property of `HtmlDocument` doesn't exist. Please review the documentation for `HtmlDocument` for a list of properties and methods that exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx. You probably want  `document.Body.InnerHtml`